# Best practice for upgrading npm `prepublish` script for npm@>=4

Tags: npm, npm-install

I run *`npm install`* from [my sample project's](https://github.com/BurtHarris/antlr4ts-json) root folder to build it using scripts in `package.json`.

The build requires a few transpilation steps currently in the **`prepublish`** script, but npm version 4 displays a warning that a breaking change is coming, leading me to believe *the new* **`prepare`** build event script is more future proof.

```
C:\code\antlr4ts-json>npm install
npm WARN prepublish-on-install As of npm@5, `prepublish` scripts will run only for `npm publish`.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install (In npm@4 and previous versions, it also runs for `npm install`.)
npm WARN prepublish-on-install See the deprecation note in `npm help scripts` for more information.
...
```

Unfortunately, simply moving the script from `prepublish` to `prepare` breaks backward compatibility: *If someone runs `npm install` using `npm@3`, the build steps in `prepare` are silently ignored.*

**What's the best practice for upgrading my build-time script?** Ideally, I'd like to update my `package.json` so that `npm install` works for any *npm@>=3*, but alternatively generating a clear error message indicating that *npm@>=4* is required at when `npm install` is run using *npm@3* would be perfectly acceptable.

Bakground:  *I tried* including

```
"engines": { "npm":  ">=4.0.0" },
```

Thanks to @toomuchdesign (and others), I understand why this doesn't do what I want; `engines` only checks when my package is installed *as a dependency*, not someone *builds it from sources*.   That makes sense.

I tracked the background on this planned change down to [npm issue #10074](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10074), which explains why a breaking change is needed.   However I'm still unclear how to handle the transition better.

Comment: I've updated this question to make it clearer I'm looking for a best practice here.  I've also updated it to point at a simpler example project at https://github.com/BurtHarris/antlr4ts-json

Comment: Corrected sample project URL:  https://github.com/BurtHarris/antlr4ts-json

Comment: Note:  I've committed my solution for this into the sample project now.

Comment: If you down-vote an answer, please leave a comment saying why...

Comment: This seems like a really big problem, the suggested solution looks like it will work but I wish there was an "official" npm suggestion for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a better solution using [`check-node-version`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-node-version); that package has a command line interface, making it easy to use for this purpose.  Here are the steps I would propose as a best-practice:

1. Add a development dependency with `npm install -D check-node-version@1`,
2. Rename the existing `prepublish` script to `prepare`,
3. Add a replacement `prepublish` script to handle backward compatibility, and suggest upgrading npm (see below.)

My **package.json** now looks something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run antlr4 && tsc",
    "prepublish": "check-node-version --npm \">=4\" || npm run prepare",
    "antlr4": "rimraf gen && antlr4ts Json.g4 -o gen -visitor",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "check-node-version": "^1.1.2",
    ...
```

With this approach:

- `npm install` always runs the `prepare` script, even with `npm@3` installed. This should presumably work correctly if `npm@5` is installed (untested.)
- On `npm@3` there's even a helpful message about upgrading npm, but because the script uses `|| npm run prepare` to simulate the behavior of later versions, the script continues after the error.
- If I later want to take a hard dependency on `npm@4`, removing the `|| npm run prepare` part would cause the script to stop if run on `npm@3`.

Here's what a build looks like using `npm@3`:

```
C:\code\antlr4ts-json>npm i

> antlr4ts-json@1.0.6-alpha prepublish C:\code\antlr4ts-json
> check-node-version --npm ">=4" || npm run prepare

node: v6.9.1
npm: v3.10.10
Error: Wanted npm version ">=4" (>=4.0.0)
To install npm, run `npm install -g npm@>=4`

> antlr4ts-json@1.0.6-alpha prepare C:\code\antlr4ts-json
> npm run antlr4 && tsc
```

Comment: Perhaps better I found [`check-node-version`](https://github.com/parshap/check-node-version#readme) already includes a CLI that can check npm versions...

Comment: However, that version check and `prepare` script won't suppress the warning. Would be good to get also rid of them.

Comment: Yup.  That's going to take a change in npm though.

Answer (score 0):

[NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) state that `engines` field casts an error only when your package is installed as a dependency:

> Unless the user has set the `engine-strict` config flag, [engines] field is advisory only will produce warnings when your package is installed as a dependency.

As developer/mantainer of the project you should not see any alert coming from your `engines` field.

Since you need to compile your files when you run `npm install` only, you might simply use `postinstall` hook.

Please also note that `prepublish` is there to stay, it will just change its behaviour on `npm@5` by firing only before `publish` hook.

Comment: OK, that explains why using the `engines` field isn't working, but I'm still looking for a best-practice to require *npm > v4* when someone runs `npm install` from within my project folder.

Comment: Thanks.   I've edited the question description to clarify I'm looking for a solution rather than just an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the [npm scripts doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) is pretty clear at the bottom:  **don't use `install`**.  I think that applies to `postinstall` as well, the only reason for those steps performing steps on end-user machine the depending on my package (not my scenario.)  But it still recommends using `prepublish` without getting any update regarding the warnings listed above.

Comment: I think I can write a script/module to address this, I'm just surprised that I can't find something that's already been published to address this.

Comment: I've written up my own solution, which I will mark as accepted.   Thanks for the assistance @toomuchdesign.